# What was the chrome:// URL that shows memory usage?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

What was the chrome url that shows memory usage by tab and gives you the opportunities to purge specific tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a hidden-url, what you're looking for the is the Chrome Task Manager you can get that with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>